# omit "to" after helping someone

Tags: grammar

So lucky to have friends helping you get the job.

So lucky to have friends helping you "to" get the job.

Which one is correct?
Is it fine that omit the to in the second sentence?

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct. It's fine to omit the 'to'. In fact, the first one sounds better.